# If...else statement in Javascript throws an TypeError

Tags: javascript

I'm starting with Javascript and I have a problem with an if-else statement.
I'm trying to use getters and setters using a private value (_num).

```
function OnlyNumbers() {
    //var _num = 123;
    var _num = "123";
    if (typeof _num === "number") {
        this.getNumber = function () {
            return _num;
        };
        this.setNumber = function (value) {
            _num = value;
            return this;
        };
    }
    else {
        console.log("It's not a number")
    }
}

var obj = new OnlyNumbers();
console.log(obj.getNumber());
//console.log(obj._num); //I wrote this value to make sure the "private" variable remains "private"
```

If I execute that code it will throw a TypeError in getNumber() because it is undefined, but if I take the if-else off, it works.
NOTE: I use the typeof because I only want to check for numbers, that's why I use that If.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
var _num = "123";
if (typeof _num === "number") {
```

_num is a string, so `typeof _num` is `"string"` which means you never assign `this.getNumber` leading to an attempt to call `undefined` as a function which results in a TypeError.

Perhaps you should restructure the code not to fail silently, and to check on all sets.

```
function OnlyNumbers() {
    var _num = 0;
    this.getNumber = function () {
        return _num;
    };
    this.setNumber = function (value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'number') {
          throw new TypeError(typeof value);
        }
        _num = value;
        return this;
    };
    this.setNumber(123);
}
```

You might also make it explicit whether NaN and the Infinities are numbers for your purposes.

If you want to coerce values like `"123"` to numbers, you could try

```
    this.setNumber = function (value) {
        _num = +value;
        return this;
    };
```

Comment: To catch that 'TypeError', Can i replace the 'throw' for a 'try-catch', right?

Comment: And the reason I use a string is to broke that code and supposed to show that 'log' instead of the error

Comment: @Kiba05, I don't follow.  If you don't want setNumber to throw, just `return this` instead.  But you will find it easier to detect and fix flaws in your program if functions like setNumber don't just ignore bad values.

Comment: I guess i didn't make myself clear ^^'
i do want numbers, but if a value is not a number, it should get the else, but then the TypeError appear, but looking at your code, i realized that i used the if-else in a wrong place, i will make a few attempts to see if i can fix it, i read i can use the isNaN(). I will edit the question in a moment.